# Pasar de un fragment del Drawer Navegation a otro activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment, activity, navigation

Buenas a todos, tengo un enorme problema, eh creado un Drawer Navegation Activity con sus respectivos fragment y lo que quiero hacer es pasar de un fragment a un activity a traves de un boton. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente debes hacer esto :

```
boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),tu_actividad.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

RECUERDA QUE PARA ENLAZAR TUS CONTROLES EN EL `onCreateView` ES ASI :

```
     View view = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_layout, container, false);
     BOTON1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.boton); // aqui ahora usas el view primero y después find...
```

**ES IMPORTANTE QUE NOTES EL CAMBIO DEl VIEW. AHORA TAMBIÉN LE AÑADES LA VISTA.**

Comment: eso solo sirve si es de un activity a otro, pero de un fragment a un activity no se puede, al momento de enlazar el boton con "findVieewId..."en el fragment no lo reconoce y tampoco el "OnClickListener"

Comment: he actualizado la respuesta @kevvelas

Comment: gracias amiga :´)

Comment: Que bueno que te haya funcionado. No olvides aceptar la respuesta como correcta, saludos @kevvelas

Comment: y como se hace eso?

Comment: Cómo se hace qué cosa ? @kevvelas

Comment: aceptar la respuesta como correcta :v (soy nuevo en esto)

Comment: Jaja en la parte superior al costado, donde yo comiendo con simplemente ... esta la opcion debajo de numero 0 @kevvelas

Comment: ahh el check no?, xD ya esta; gracias por tu ayuda